# How to create a file and then read integers of it and give an average?

Tags: python, integer, average

I have to write a program that reads a list of numbers from a file then outputs the average.
If my file contained
3
45
83
21
My program would output: 38
I know how to create the file:

```
myFile = open('average', 'wt')
myFile.write('3\n')
myFile.write('45\n')
myFile.write('83\n')
myFile.write('21\n')
myFile.close()
```

This bit works but I don't know how to do the second part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open('average', 'wt') as myFile:
    myFile.write('3\n')
    myFile.write('45\n')
    myFile.write('83\n')
    myFile.write('21\n')
```

Split number string using [`str.split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#str.split), then convert to int. [Sum](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) all number, divide it:

```
with open('average', 'rt') as myFile:
    numbers = map(int, myFile.read().split())
    print(sum(numbers, 0.0) / len(numbers))
```

If file is huge, above will cause problem (taking too many memory). In such case, use following (process line by line):

```
with open('average', 'rt') as myFile:
    total, n = 0, 0
    for line in myFile:
        total += int(line)
        n += 1
    print(float(total) / n)
```

Comment: The `t` in the file modes is totally superfluous; as is giving an explicit mode to `open` when you only want to read the file. I'd recommend omitting them for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

This code should do what you want.

```
numbers = [int(f.strip()) for f in open("average").readlines()]
print(sum(numbers)/float(len(numbers)))
```

It uses [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) in order to build a list of all the numbers in the file, it uses `strip()` to remove the newline character `\n` from the line, then it uses `int()` to convert the number to an integer (at this point, the number was still a string). The file itself is read using `readlines()` which outputs a list of all the lines in the file.

Finally, it prints the sum of all the numbers in the list divided by the length of the list (which gives the average of all the numbers).